# Disable a CalendarEventAction from angular-calendar

Tags: javascript, angular, types, angular-calendar

I have 2 actions ,

```js
  actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [

    {
      label: '<i class="material-icons mat-icon">edit</i>',
      
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
         this.editCalendarEvent(event);
    }
    }, {
      label: '<i class="material-icons mat-icon">remove</i>',
      
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
         this.removeCalendarEvent(event);
    }
    },
]
```

But I want only a user with a role  (example: administrator) to see the second icon, the remove event.

How can I hide the second icon for the rest of the users and display it for the administrator.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've haven't played with angular yet so I'm by no means the best person to answer this question, so hopefully someone comes along with a better solution. However for the time being you could just add a condition inside your `onClick` function that checks if the user has permission.

```
onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
    if(user.admin) {
        this.removeCalendarEvent(event);
    } else {
        alert("--!!! You Don't Have Permission To Perform This Action !!!--");
    }
}
```

You could also try onload adding a `onload` function to your label and check if the user is an admin as before, and if not you could set `label.disabled="true"`

```
...
label: '<i onload="checkPermission()" id="removeBtn" class="material-icons mat-icon">remove</i>',
...

checkPermission() => {
    if(!user.admin) {
       document.getElementById("removeBtn").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

or just hide the button altogether

```
...document.getElementById("removeBtn").display = "hidden";
...
```

You would want pull the user data (such as roles) from your database on the backend. You could use node.js for that. If not you're more susceptible to people gaining admin privileges via the console.